# What does the expression "brikking it" mean?

Tags: idioms, verbs

I have a British friend, and we text each other sometimes. Yesterday she sent me a message with the expression "brikking it". Could someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 4):

I am not afraid to spell it out for the avoidance of doubt. *Bricking it* is derived from *shitting a brick*, meaning *being very afraid*.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen it spelt that way, but [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bricking%20it) gives the meaning I am aware of, basically "scared" but complete with all the unpleasant connotations given.